# App Store In-App Popup in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add a feature that allows people to download other apps of mine from within the app.

If I simply link to the App Store, it will boot the user to the App Store app and display my app, however I want an in-app method. I've seen this on Facebook's iOS app. How do I implement this sort of system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is from the AppStore URL
https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8

```
SKStoreProductViewController* productViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
[productViewController loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:@(284882215)} completionBlock:nil];
[productViewController setDelegate:self];   //  Implement the delegate to make the cancel button work
[self presentViewController:productViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```